# Speed up MYSQL Left join query containing 100K+ records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, thinking-sphinx

The query is generated by thinking sphinx. I'm looking at ways to speed up this query. It virtually takes forever to return the results. Is there any way we can optimize this.

```
SELECT 
    SQL_NO_CACHE `meetings`.`id` * CAST(8 AS SIGNED) + 3 AS `id`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(' ', `members`.`first_name`, `members`.`last_name`), '0') SEPARATOR ' ') AS `mentor_name`, 
    `meetings`.`id` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 
    0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, 
    984144037 AS `class_crc`, 
    `meetings`.`program_id` AS `program_id`, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`meetings`.`start_time`) AS `start_time`, 
    `meetings`.`active` AS `active`, 
    `meetings`.`calendar_time_available` AS `calendar_time_available`, 
    `meetings`.`group_id` AS `group_id` 
FROM `meetings` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_meetings` 
    ON `member_meetings`.`meeting_id` = `meetings`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `members` 
    ON `members`.`id` = `member_meetings`.`member_id` 
WHERE 
    `meetings`.`delta` = 0 
GROUP BY 
    `meetings`.`id` 
ORDER BY NULL
```

**Counts**

```
select count(*) from meetings : 194685
select count(*) from member_meetings : 522309
select count(*) from members : 112016
```

**EDIT**

I have figured out the issue, I had all the appropriate indexes configured correctly

A duplicate index key was added for member_meetings.meeting_id and member_meetings.member_id, Turns out that there is a bug in rails ActiveRecord::Migration when using the add_index method. I have now removed the duplicate index key, the query response time was only 4s

Comment: never mind the performance, this query has a problem with the group by clause, so its results wont be what you expect; add all the non-aggregated columns to the group by clause

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have indexes on

```
`member_meetings`.`meeting_id`
`meetings`.`id` 
`members`.`id`
`member_meetings`.`member_id` 
`meetings`.`delta`
```

Comment: I had all these indexes, But duplicate index key was added, Turns out that there is a bug in rails ActiveRecord::Migration when using the add_index method. I have now removed the duplicate index key, the query response time was only 4s

Comment: So check the indexes was the answer, but rather than adding them you had to remove a duplicate.